# group records according to column

Tags: oracle

hi how can make this result query:

[image]

to this:

[image]

I have this code and i know it's still farfetched:

```
select
        max(case subcod when 'DISABILITY' then A end) as disability,
        max(case subcod when 'DISMEMBERMENT' then B end) as dismemberment,
        max(case subcod when 'MEDICAL' then C end) as medical,
        max(case subcod when 'OTHERS' then D end) as others
    from
        (
        select subcod, description as A, null as B, null as C, null as D from grp_appl_ref where ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'DISABILITY'
        union
        select subcod, null, description, null, null from grp_appl_ref where ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'DISMEMBERMENT'
        union
        select subcod, null, null, description, null from grp_appl_ref where ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'MEDICAL'
        union
        select subcod, null, null, null, description from grp_appl_ref where ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'OTHERS'
        )
```

I was wondering if there's another reserved word instead of max so i can remove the null values so the cells with values would move up.

is it possible?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE statement as following

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'DISABILITY' THEN   description ELSE NULL END AS DISABILITY,
CASE WHEN ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'DISMEMBERMENT' THEN   description ELSE NULL END AS DISMEMBERMENT,
CASE WHEN ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'MEDICAL' THEN   description ELSE NULL END AS MEDICAL,
CASE WHEN ref_id = 'RIDERS' and subcod = 'OTHERS' THEN   description ELSE NULL END AS OTHERS
FROM grp_appl_ref
```

If at any stage need to sort out records while putting NULL values at the end use CASE statement in ORDER BY clause

```
ORDER BY CASE columnName WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I think this will still result in the above image and not the one with the yellow header.